# Spread to wide format based on conditions

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a long dataset that looks something like this

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
Year <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
          1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9)
treatID <- c(NA,NA,NA,"CCQ_A",NA,NA,"CCQ_C",NA,NA,
             NA,"CCQ+A",NA,"IOT+B","CCQ_K",NA,NA,"IOT_B",NA,NA)
SecondID <- c(NA,NA,NA,"CCQ",NA,NA,"CCQ",NA,NA,
              NA,"CCQ",NA,"IOT","CCQ",NA,NA,"IOT",NA,NA)
cond <- c(NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,
          NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA)
val <- c(NA,NA,NA,3,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,
         NA,3,NA,4,5,NA,NA,1,NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(ID,Year,treatID,SecondID,cond, val)
```

Grouping by ID, I would like to create a wide dataset based on the following conditions:

1) if `cond!=1` the data should be spread based on the variable `treatID`, (and include the `val` scores)

2) if `cond==1` the data should be spread based on the variable `SecondID`(and include the `val` scores)

The final dataset should look something like this

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
Year <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
          1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
CCQ_A <- c(NA,NA,NA,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
           NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
CCQ_C <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,
            NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
S_ID_CCQ <-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
           NA,3,NA,NA,5,NA,NA,NA,NA)
S_ID_IOT <-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             NA,NA,NA,4,NA,NA,NA,1,NA)
final <- data.frame(ID,Year,CCQ_A,CCQ_C,S_ID_CCQ, S_ID_IOT)
```

Please do not that `S_ID` has been added to identify which columns have been using the `SecondID` variable to classify

I am able to spread with one condition `wide<- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% spread (treatID, val)` but I am not sure how to go about multiple conditions.

Also, please do note that df includes some duplicated observations when it comes to `Year` and `ID` identifiers (i.e. there are two rows for `ID=B` and `Year=4`) while the final dataset has only one observation for `ID=B` and `Year=4`. This is not an essential element of this question, but it would be great if you could help me also with this

I hope this is clear

Thank you a lot in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alex, hope this might be helpful. There may be a number of strategies for this. One way would be to use two `pivot_longer` statements and join the resulting data frames.

Below is another way, where you first use `pivot_longer` so you have all of your IDs in one column. Then, you can filter based on condition to select rows with either `treatID` or `SecondID`.

In the end, you can use `pivot_wider` to get the columns you need.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(treatID, SecondID), names_to = "ID_Type", values_to = "ID_Value", names_repair = "minimal") %>%
  filter(if_else(cond != 1 | is.na(cond), ID_Type == "treatID", ID_Type == "SecondID")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("ID", "Year", "cond"), names_from = c("ID_Type", "ID_Value"), values_from = "val") %>%
  select(-c(cond, treatID_NA))
```

This gave these results with your sample data:

```
# A tibble: 18 x 6
   ID     Year treatID_CCQ_A treatID_CCQ_C SecondID_CCQ SecondID_IOT
   <fct> <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 A         1            NA            NA           NA           NA
 2 A         2            NA            NA           NA           NA
 3 A         3            NA            NA           NA           NA
 4 A         4             3            NA           NA           NA
 5 A         5            NA            NA           NA           NA
 6 A         6            NA            NA           NA           NA
 7 A         7            NA             2           NA           NA
 8 A         8            NA            NA           NA           NA
 9 A         9            NA            NA           NA           NA
10 B         1            NA            NA           NA           NA
11 B         2            NA            NA            3           NA
12 B         3            NA            NA           NA           NA
13 B         4            NA            NA            5            4
14 B         5            NA            NA           NA           NA
15 B         6            NA            NA           NA           NA
16 B         7            NA            NA           NA            1
17 B         8            NA            NA           NA           NA
18 B         9            NA            NA           NA           NA
```

A couple of things I noticed:

One, there were a couple of values for `ID == B` and `Year == 4 and Year == 7` based on the data, which looks different than your results.

Second, you could deal with duplicate observations in different ways. How would you like to deal with them? What would be your desired outcome?

Comment: Dear Ben thanks a lot this is great! I was able to to find a way to deal with the duplicated observations :)